# How can I host a wifi from either a lan connection or wifi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to host a wifi from either a lan connection (if available) or either sharing a network.

I did use the tutorial : [https://kaiuwe.hüber.de/raspberry-pi-wifi-repeater-ohne-adapter/](https://kaiuwe.h%C3%BCber.de/raspberry-pi-wifi-repeater-ohne-adapter/)
But this just acts as a repeater ...

My expectation is a possibility to share wifi over wlan or when a lan connection is active share the wifi from lan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you know enough about WiFi or TCP/IP networking to ask your question sensibly.  What do you mean by "share WiFi?"  There are two common scenarios:

1. Your Pi works as a WiFi bridge to an Ethernet LAN.  In this case, the WiFi and the LAN are the "same" network, just different media.  For instance, if your LAN uses the IPv4 address 192.168.42.0-255, your WiFi users will also share this network.
2. Your Pi works as a WiFi router, with an Ethernet LAN as the "uplink."  In this case, your WiFi network has its own range of addresses, probably managed by your Pi, and the Pi works as a router between the WLAN and the LAN.  This is like what most home WiFi access points do.  (You will probably need to have the Pi do Network Address Translation as well.  For some reason, Linux people insist on calling this 'masquerading.')

If you can clarify which of those you want to do, I could provide some pointers going forward.  You many want to do some reading on the basics of TCP/IP networking first.  If you don't know how a bridge and a router differ, you won't be able to ask useful questions.